# Positioning unconnected bones in pose mode using cursor

Tags: armature, bones

I'm still learning and I am currently having problems positioning unconnected bones accurately in pose mode when using the 3d cursor.

I have one bone positioned correctly and I then need to add a new unconnected bone so I select bone 1 in edit mode and then press Shift+A to add a new bone. I then need to align it to a object so I switch to pose mode and then select the object and press shift+S and select cursor to selected, then I select the bone and press shift+S and select selection to cursor. The bone is now positioned correctly but if I switch to edit mode then the bone is in the wrong position. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: All your bones need to be positioned correctly in Edit mode. In Edit mode you will build the basic/rest pose of the character. All the changes you will make in Pose mode are only for animations purpose (or to create static particular poses) and won't affect the bone positions in Edit mode. So if the bone aligned to an object is supposed to be the rest pose, you have to do it in Edit mode. But maybe that does not answer to your question, in that case you should give a screenshot so that we understand correctly what is your problem.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. Instead of positioning in pose mode I'll just use edit mode.

Comment: yes, don't build you Rest pose accordingly to what particular pose your character could take at a moment or at another, just build a very standard Rest pose in Edit mode, with legs straight and arms horizontal. Then in Pose mode you'll make him move the way you want. And in Pose mode, to come back to the Rest pose, i.e. the same bone positions as in Edit mode, select all your bones and alt R (to reset rotations), alt S (to reset scales) and alt G (to reset movements).

Comment: But it's not clear what you meant by aligning a bone to an object, so maybe you should precise this. If for example your character move to take an object or to take a particular position, do it in Pose mode.`

Comment: by aligning a bone I mean that I need a bone to be in the center of a object. When I was doing this in pose mode using cursor to selected, then selected to cursor the bone positioned changed when switching to edit mode. But if I do the same procedure in edit mode it works fine. Thanks for your help it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your bones need to be positioned correctly in *Edit* mode. In *Edit* mode you will build the basic/rest pose of the character. All the changes you will make in *Pose* mode are only for animations purpose (or to create static particular poses) and won't affect the bone positions in *Edit* mode. So if the bone aligned to an object is supposed to be the rest pose, you have to do it in *Edit* mode, if this is supposed to be an animation pose, do it in *Pose* mode.